# Spark Java Returns 404 For All Endpoints

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, spark-java

I have configured this endpoint and many others just like it.  All endpoints return 404.  I packaged my .jar in a kubernetes container.  In the logs, I see "the requested route [/hello] has not been mapped in Spark".  It obviously has, though.

I've been googling like crazy trying to find answers to questions that sort of match.

I know that my server is up and running because it is returning the 404.  I also know that it runs long enough to have created the endpoint because of some additional information that shows up in my logs.

```
get("/hello", (req, res) -> {
    res.status(200);
    res.type("text/plain");
    return "Hello, World!  This is DataPeddler v1";
});
```

Comment: If you're running your server in a container it might be an issue not related to your code, for example exposing the ports. Make sure your server is running properly without the container first.

Comment: It is!  We verified.  Thank you, though!

Comment: So if it is running properly without the container then it's probably a problem related to docker/k8s - try to add these tags to your question.